# EntityManager inside Entity Bean how-to

Tags: entity, ejb-3.0, entitymanager

How to use (inject) entityManager to Entity Bean?
Inside my Entity bean I have some validations that need to do query on other (unrelated) Entity, some kind of List-Of-Values Entity. What is the right way to do this? To put EntityManager to a constructor of Entity Bean? Or what?

Comment: Similar one, can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9726342/366964

Answer (score 3):

Entity beans do not (in general) support injection of any kind because they are not created by the container.

This general topic was recently [discussed](http://java.net/projects/jpa-spec/lists/jsr338-experts/archive/2011-06/message/13) on the JSR-338 (JPA 2.1) mailing list and [reasons](http://java.net/projects/jpa-spec/lists/jsr338-experts/archive/2011-06/message/18) [were](http://java.net/projects/jpa-spec/lists/jsr338-experts/archive/2011-06/message/24) [given](http://java.net/projects/jpa-spec/lists/jsr338-experts/archive/2011-06/message/44) why it is generally considered a bad idea for entities to reference entity managers.